# Set up for working offline and uploading to remote site

Tags: drupal, editor, workflow

I am currently using Komodo edit for coding, and have a set up where I am using MAMP and a local install of Drupal, and SASS to build my site offline.

Once its ready test online, I upload onto the remote site. However, then I am working sometimes on the remote site and sometimes on the local one, and finding some problems.

I'm not using SASS on the remote site, so I am working in the CSS file. I don't have all the Drupal panels in code yet, so I'm having to rebuild them on the remote site, and I'm making tweaks and changes on the fly.

I end up with two slightly different versions of the site and need to keep track of the changes I want to keep from both. What can I do to clean up my workflow?

It would be better if I could work entirely locally and then sync that to the remote environment.

With something like Netbeans I think I could have a local copy of the site running and then right click and upload each file onto the remote server so there are two copies of the file.

I could do with some advice as to what the cleanest set up is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an actual Dev server with its own ip and a live server with its own ip but they both connect to the same mysql server. There are two databases set up, db1 and db2.

I use a php script with basic sql instructions to:

Check which db is in use.
Backup that db (say, db1).
Sync the databases
Import that db into db2.

Once that is done, I use this:

```
cp webdb2.settings.php settings.php
```

So I always have two databases available and can roll right back (in this case with:
`cp webdb1.settings.php settings.php`) if something when wrong.

This seems to be a pretty good system. I only ever work on the dev, and then push it to the live with the process above.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing that you can do is work offline an then sync the content (themes/modules) when you have to.

If you work on both you could lose data or lose track of code changes.

Comment: also a nice and easier option